# X server 8 bit pseudo color initiating the palette (linux xdoom)

Tags: linux, x11, color-palette

I' looking at the original 1997 32 bit port of xDoom for Linux which I have running on Ubuntu 64 bit.

Sound and input is working and I am getting graphical output but the colors are all wrong.

The code assumes an 8 bit pseudo screen and I have used Xypher (Xserver) to provide a window that is 8 bits deep.

So I get the impression xDoom assumes this 8 256 pseudo color screen has a fixed/default palette of colors which the X window does not have.

So I need to know two things:

- what is the color palette for a 256 pseudo color X window
- how can I use a script/program to assign colors to the X window prior to xDoom launching.

At this point I'm assuming 8 bit RGB 3x3x2, but I don't really know.

My startup script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
Xephyr :2 -ac -br -screen 1280x800x8 -reset -terminate -title DOOM &
#DISPLAY=:2 ./setupcolorpalette
DISPLAY=:2 ./linuxxdoom -4 -warp 1 1
```

I need some ideas regarding doing this in script or code!

Comment: Found this which describes 8bit pseudo color as an 8 bit index into 24 million colours. https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/X11PseudocolorAndWMs So my 3x3x2 format is not correct!

Comment: Looking deeper into the code it appears xdoom explicitly sets up the colormap. So why the colors are coming out wrong is a mystery.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I unfortunately did not find a solution!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  Fixed by adding the following line to `i_video.c` around line 819 (just before the call to XDefineCursor).

```
XInstallColormap(X_display, X_cmap);
```

I found this fix in a closed PullRequest for DOOM here: https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM/pull/2/files#diff-ecac9183c706456b9a28129cc023c038R820